# Does the .containsKey() method return null pointer exception?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap and I need to check if a certain value is present as a key in the hashmap. The problem is the first time I need to perform the check, the hashmap can be empty or null. Will the .containsKey() do the job of returning false if the hashmap is null or empty in this case or should I add an additional null pointer check?

```
Map<String, String> groupNameMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
if(abc!= null && !groupNameMap.containsKey(abc)){
        usersGroupName = getGroupName(abc,xyz,oci);


        }
```

Will this piece of code solve the problem? the groupNameMap can be either empty or null.

Comment: Could you post stack trace?

Comment: In the case when the map is null, put it this way. If the map is null, what are you looking in to find a key? `containsKey` can't even return false if there isn't a map to look for a key in to begin with.

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc?  Did you try it?

Comment: No.. containsKey doesnt check whether your map is null... It is only concerned with returning the value corresponding to the key( yes the key/value could be null)

Comment: This would be best ... in practice ... 

    if ( null != map && map..containsKey(abc))
    {
        .... 
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> groupNameMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Since you are creating the instance of the Map before calling containsKey() on it, no NPE will occur.

`groupNameMap` cannot be null by your piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

if `groupNameMap` could be null, check it.

and, you don't need check whether key  `abc` is `null` or not, `null` is a valid key in `Map`